# Custom launchers don't work like normal launchers, and allow application switching?

Tags: unity, launcher

Using `gnome-desktop-item-edit`, I created a custom launcher for Chrome. When I use the launcher, it doesn't show the arrow next to the icon in the Unity launcher, so any windows I open are unmanageable, and don't even show up while alt-tabbing.

This is the launch command: `/opt/google/chrome/chrome --allow-file-access-from-files`

How do I create a launcher that creates normal, alt-tabbable windows?

Comment: I use the following to launch: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome %U

Answer (score 1):

In Gedit or a text editor create the file below and save it to your desktop with a name like "chrome-file-access.desktop" Then drag the icon onto the launcher. Change the icon image to something unique.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Chrome File Access
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
Icon=/home/Pictures/my_icon_here.png
```