# GnuCash not showing up in launcher?

Tags: unity, 12.04, launcher

Since yesterday (8th May 2012) I don't know what has changed - several unity updates come through but now whenever I open gnuCash it doesn't show in the unity launcher bar when it's open and I can't <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> between it and other open applications.

This makes it impossible to switch between it and other apps.

Comment: This also happens with K3b - I don't know if this is because it's a KDE app but sometimes it disappears from the Unity Launcher bar and sometimes it's there. If it's not shown in the bar then I can't alt & Tab between it and other open apps.

Comment: OP flagged as too localised - " It no longer applies as it's automatically been resolved by some updates which came through"

Comment: This is happening to me now on Ubuntu 12.10--not with GnuCash, but with a few other programs (Skype, Archive Manager (aka `file-roller`), gedit). But I guess I need to upgrade to 13.04 and see if it's fixed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that the shortcut "Super +W" shows all the windows, even if there is the issue you describe. So, just a temporary solution, but it works well :-)

Comment: Now this is a good option Super & W. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Open a **terminal window** and initiate **Gnucash** from there. You should see error messages in the terminal that should help you discover the problem.

Comment: Hi, Srinivas. Now that you have enough rep to comment, please don't use the answer section to request more info. Thanks

Comment: Hi Srinivas, when I open gnuCash again - either by terminal or dash it just says that it's already open. I can't get back to the window to close it or use it at all.

Comment: Oh ya sorry about that.. ;-)

Comment: Well I guess your not the only one facing this problem have read of this.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/105146/custom-launchers-dont-work-like-normal-launchers-and-and-allow-application-swi

Comment: I've now tried restarting unity by typing "unity" in a command line and that didn't help! So I logged out and back in. Problem is still there but if I add gnuCash to the unity bar then this sorts it out. Any ideas why?

Comment: But this only changed after yesterday's updates? So something has changed from yesterday to today!

Comment: I guess there are some incompatible library files that don't integrate well with Unity.

Comment: And are you using the Unity-revamped PPA to enable the window dodge behavior ?

Comment: No - I haven't added the Unity-revamped PPA.